# BOOK: Polyhedra and Polytopes (soft question)

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, polyhedra, polytopes

Turns out that I've recently started getting into *Robust Control* techniques, which are mostly based on the assumption that a nominal ordinary differential equation is "perturbed" by a suitably defined "uncertainty" element $\Delta$ (usually defined as a linear mapping).

$\Delta$ is virtually always assumed to be contained in a polytope, defined in a finite-dimensional Euclidean space.

That said, I'm super interested in (formal) literature on polyhedra and polytopes. And I would appreciate recommendations from the community. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See the list of Works (i.e. section 3) of the Wiki article about H.S.M. Coxeter.

Comment: Since it seems you are coming from an applied direction, I would go for the initial sections of Ziegler's "Lectures on Polytopes".